# RSA how to disable Transferring files do IBM "feature"

Tags: java, eclipse, rational-rsa

My RSA is very slow and most of times it tries run a thread named "transferring files to IBM". I don't want really share any stuff with IBM at all! There is any way to disable such "feature" because it is very annoying!

```
IBM Rational® Software Architect

Version: 8.0.3
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.specification.version=1.6
java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferencesFactory
java.vendor=IBM Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://www.ibm.com/
java.version=1.6.0
java.vm.info=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 8 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr13-20130114_134867 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20130114_134867
JIT  - r9_20130108_31100
GC   - 20121212_AA
java.vm.name=IBM J9 VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.vm.specification.version=1.0
java.vm.vendor=IBM Corporation
java.vm.version=2.4
jxe.current.romimage.version=15
jxe.lowest.romimage.version=15
line.separator=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem I seem to have fixed it.

On this page, it talks about enabling/disabling "Product Feedback" which I believe causes the issue:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W0c4a14ff363e_436c_9962_2254bb5cbc60/page/Using%20the%20Product%20Feedback%20utility

Steps to fix:

- Go to Window -> Preferences
- Then go to [General -> Product Feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdYB1.png) and select the radio box for "Never send any data"

I've disabled it there and haven't seen the issue since.